# Difference between style spread syntax and array syntax in React-Native

Tags: react-native, styles

I been using react native for a while and add this issue:

When using `style={[style.container, { height: this.state.position }]}` my view wasn't setting the desired height and my component was messed up. But then came across with `style={{...style.container, height: this.state.position }}` and my styles where working as expected.

What is the difference between on and the other?